# How to use Single NSTimer instance and use it to update data in many viewControllers?

Tags: iphone, nstimer

I want to show countdowntimer in more than 5 viewControllers and they will appear at different time, how to use single NSTimer instance to update all view countdown???

Answer (score 0):

Put the timer in a single view controller and give this controller references to all the other ones. When the timer goes off you call the method in the other controllers.

That's the concept anyway. How you structure it is up to you.